# Why the object is not getting close enough to the waypoint/s too high?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToMove;
    public GameObject[] waypoints;
    public Transform target;
    public float moveSpeed = 1f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 1f;
    private Transform myTransform;
    private int targetsIndex = 0;
    private Vector3 originalPosition;
    private bool visitNpcsDistance = false;

    public float walkSpeed = 15f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        if (objectToMove == null)
        {
            myTransform = transform;
        }
        else
        {
            myTransform = objectToMove.transform;
        }

        originalPosition = myTransform.position;

        if (waypoints.Length == 0)
        {
            waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Waypoint");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (visitNpcsDistance == false)
        {
            WayPointsAI();
        }

        DrawLinesInScene();
    }

    private void WayPointsAI()
    {
        if (targetsIndex == waypoints.Length)
            targetsIndex = 0;
        target = waypoints[targetsIndex].transform;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(myTransform.position, target.transform.position);
        myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        //move towards the player
        myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (distance < 0.3f)
            targetsIndex++;
    }

    void DrawLinesInScene()
    {
        // draw lines between each checkpoint //
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(waypoints[i].transform.position, waypoints[i + 1].transform.position, Color.blue);
        }

        // draw a line between the original transform start position
        // and the current transform position //
        Debug.DrawLine(originalPosition, myTransform.position, Color.red);

        // draw a line between current transform position and the next waypoint target
        // each time reached a waypoint.
        if (target != null)
            Debug.DrawLine(target.transform.position, myTransform.position, Color.green);
    }
}
```

The object that move between the waypoints. I added to it a box collider and set the size of the collider to 0.4,0.4,0.4 it was 0.5,0.5,0.5

The moving object also have a rigidbody I added :

[image: Droid moving object between the waypoints]

Each waypoints sphere WP1,WP2....scale is set to 0.3,0..3,0.3

I added some spheres as waypoints on a stairs so the object will move up and down the stairs.
But when it's moving up and down the object seems to be too far from the waypoints :

[image: Too high from waypoints]

Look at the droid (the object that move between the waypoints) height and it's not 0.3f distance from the waypoint/s. I don't want the droid to walk on the stairs move on it touch the stairs I want it to be in the air a bit but not that high.

The droid selected and set to center and local :

[image: Center and Local]

when changing the local to global nothing changed but when changing the center to pivot :

[image: changed center to pivot]

Comment: Can you select your drone object, and [set your gizmo handle position toggles to "Pivot / Local"](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/GizmoDisplayToggles_01.png) and show us what you see? It looks like your object's origin - the part that navigates between waypoints - is about 1.4 units lower than the mesh.

Comment: There you go. Move the object's mesh lower, closer to its pivot, and its hover height will be adjusted accordingly.